# Problema ao executar um script via shell utilizando o Zenity. Mensagem: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, gui

Quando executo o **script.sh** via shell linux, aparece essa mensagem: **Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.**
Como faço para solucionar essa questão?

```
#!/bin/bash

get_url ()
{
    url=$(zenity --entry --title="Youtube" --text="Criado por: Leandro Sciola\\nCole o link do vídeo aqui para extrair o áudio:" --ok-label=Extrair --width="600" height="50")

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        exit
    fi
}

download ()
{
    (
        youtube-dl -f m4a --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --print-json --no-warnings $url >metadata
    ) | zenity --progress --title="Youtube" --pulsate --auto-close --no-cancel --text "Extraindo o áudio..."

    title=$(jq -r ".title" metadata)
    rm metadata

    if [ "$title" ]; then
        zenity --info --title="Youtube" --text="Áudio extraído com sucesso!\\nTítulo: $title"
    else
        zenity --error --title="Youtube" --text="Erro! Não foi possível extrair o áudio!"
        setup
    fi
}

setup ()
{
    get_url

    if [ "$url" ]; then
        download
    else
        zenity --warning --title="Youtube" --text="Nenhum link foi adicionado no campo!"
        setup
    fi
}

setup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mensagens de aviso no GTK são algo frequentes e muitas vezes, como no presente caso, podem ser ignoradas sem que haja qualquer problema.

Neste caso específico, para traduzir em linguagem inteligível, a mensagem está dizendo: *"janelas de diálogo devem ser iniciadas por outras janelas"*, ou seja, devem ter janelas-mãe. Isso garante que o *window manager* consiga saber o que é aplicação e o que é diálogo, saber quais janelas estão associadas a uma mesma aplicação, etc.

Dessa forma, trata-se de um aviso inerente ao uso do Zenity, porque é justamente um caso em que janelas de diálogo vêm, direta e legitimamente, de uma interface de linha de comando! Note que a mensagem diz que tal prática é desencorajada, mas não diz que isso é um erro. A existência da mensagem não afeta em nenhum modo a execução do seu script.

Como não há forma do Zenity inibir o retorno de mensagens do GTK, caso você queira manter a console limpa quando da execução do script, sugiro que redirecione a saída de erro das chamadas `zenity` para o `/dev/null`, por exemplo:

```
    url=$(zenity --entry --title ... height="50" 2> /dev/null);
```

Sugiro também que isso seja feito após garantido que as chamadas ao `zenity` não falhem, pois isso inibe qualquer saída de erro e pode dificultar o processo de *debug*.

Referência: [linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/%5Bsolved%5D-gtk-message-gtkdialog-mapped-without-a-transient-parent-this-is-discouraged-4175550278/)

Comment: Eu não sabia disso. Valeu!!!